# Ionic-5 apk build failed

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Execution failed for task ':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:processDebugManifest'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

I'm getting this error . Please help.

Comment: show errors code.


are you using gps permission?? then check this
"<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"/>"

Comment: I can make specific changes in local. But, when I build the apk through bot then how can we fix this issue?